# Is Cyclomatic Complexity of '267' better?

Tags: c#, .net, cyclomatic-complexity

I have developed an application in .NET using C#.

Using 'Calculate code metrics' option, I got the cyclomatic complexity score of '267' with 2,348 lines of code and Depth of Inheritance = 7, Class Coupling = 150 and Maintainability index = 80.

I know the lower the cyclomatic complexity, the better it is. Though I am unaware of the rest of the parameters, I wish to know if the cyclomatic complexity of 267 is better or not?

Comment: Better than what? You can't say something is better or worse if there's nothing to compare it to.

Comment: I *think* lower the better on all of the above. Make sure you're following [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

Comment: For the maintainability index, higher is better - "an index value between 0 and 100 that represents the relative ease of maintaining the code. A high value means better maintainability. Color coded ratings can be used to quickly identify trouble spots in your code. A green rating is between 20 and 100 and indicates that the code has good maintainability. A yellow rating is between 10 and 19 and indicates that the code is moderately maintainable. A red rating is a rating between 0 and 9 and indicates low maintainability." ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385914.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cyclomatic complexity typically refers to the number of independent paths through your code. This is measured by the following formula in Visual Studio:

```
Complexity = Edges - Nodes + 1
```

For any given method, 25 is considered to be dangerously high and causes Visual Studio to throw an error. Ideally, you want to keep cyclomatic complexity as low as possible. Try aiming for 3-4 and maxing out at around 10.

For an entire project, this number is likely not meaningful enough to compare between separate projects. If you are refactoring code, you can use this as a metric to help identify whether you are having an impact on reducing overall complexity.

However, be careful with using these types of metrics as the sole indicator of a project's health. Without a clear question or goal, they can mislead you and waste time or worse. You may be better off focusing on another metric like code coverage before trying to reduce cyclomatic complexity.

You can read more about cyclomatic complexity here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182212.aspx

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity

Comment: You're numbers apply to the cyclomatic complexity of a single method, while I'm guessing (hoping) that OP is talking about the cyclomatic complexity of (at least) a project.

Comment: My cyclomatic complexity comes in at 9,265. Did the way they measure this change?